# Can I save an .ai file as a .psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, save

I have a large 300mb layered .ai file containing .jpg and .psd images. I would like to save it as a Photoshop.psd file. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Open the AI file with Photoshop.... Do you need layer structure in tact? What's the purpose of needing Photoshop??

Comment: Wow 300 MB is huge for an Illustrator file. No wonder you'd like to put it in Photoshop. If all else fails you should be able copy your vector elements and paste as layers in a new Photoshop document.

Answer (score 4):

Go to File > Export from Illustrator and choose "PSD" as your file type.